# Can I tell Perl that some data are immutable to speed things up?

Tags: perl, optimization

Perl is really good for writing the kind of string/file parsing programs that I usually need to do. What I really love is the insignificant amount of time it takes me to write quick scripts and throwaway code, compared to C/C++/JAVA. However, I want to learn how to speed things up.

For example, I would want to learn how to give hints to Perl so that it can make some decisions better—especially things related to strings. It seems to me that Perl copies a string whenever you do anything regardless of whether you really modify the copy later or not. Is this by design (and can I turn that away using some magic?) or am I ranting?

I really want to treat some strings as `(const char *`). I am sure we always do not need everything to be a std::string with all its baggage involved (let's assume std::string to be analogous to Perl string). Can I give a hint to Perl to do that on some strings?

I remember reading in some article (please comment if you can place it) that you can hint to Perl that you will not modify some variable and thus it removes the extra baggage that is otherwise required if you were to modify it, etc.

I believe Perl variables have two internal pointers to a same Perl variable—one can store a number and another a string (array of characters). Could I always tell Perl to choose one throughout? Could I make Perl treat some strings as `(const char *)` so that they do not tag around functionality required to modify them?

For example, I read somewhere (maybe the same article?) that unpack() is faster than substr() because substr() returns a lvalue, so that you can operate on it as well. For example, if I wanted to replace the first two characters of a string with 'ef', I could write:

```
substr(string, 0, 2) = 'ef'; # string now begins with 'ef'
```

Hence, unless I am using this special feature of substr(), am I better off using substr?

Did I just rant all the way through?

Comment: You mean

      substr(string, 0, 2) = 'ef';

in your example.

Comment: Yes Daniel! But for some reason I cannot make the fix anymore - it keeps on saying page not found :-(

Comment: I personally have never seen a single case where strings being used were my performance bottleneck. They just use more memory, and we tend to have bucket loads of that these days. You need to be doing some *seriously* heavy string work to have memory / performance problems, and if you hit that, you're probably just doing something wrong.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can set the `SvREADONLY` flag on a variable with [`Readonly::XS`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Readonly-XS/XS.pm), but that does not improve the efficiency.  Efficiency comes from choosing the right algorithm, not through compiler hints.  If you want your code to be faster/use less memory then profile it (see [`Devel::NYTProf`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Devel-NYTProf/lib/Devel/NYTProf.pm)).  When you find a bottleneck either use a different algorithm there or switch to use [`XS`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlxs.html).

Also, if you are going to try to optimize something, make sure the result really is faster, here is substr vs unpack:

```
            Rate unpack substr
unpack 2055647/s     --   -74%
substr 7989875/s   289%     --
```

Here is the benchmark code.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Benchmark;

my %subs = (
    unpack => sub { return unpack "a3", "foobarbaz" },
    substr => sub { return substr "foobarbaz", 0, 3 }
);

for my $sub (keys %subs) {
    print "$sub => ", $subs{$sub}(), "\n";
}

Benchmark::cmpthese -1, \%subs;
```

Answer (score 7):

### in general:

Use good algorithms and don't optimize unless it is necessary.  If it is, profile your code and  benchmark your changes.  This is a good time to consider XS or Inline::C as needed.

### a (const *) char equvialent:

`use constant Foo => 'bar';` creates [a minimal subroutine that can be inlined](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Constant-Functions) by the perl compiler.  You can also create your own inlineable constant functions

### avoid extra copying:

The typical perl idiom does some "extra" copying:

```
sub foo {
    my $bar = shift;

    ..do stuff with $bar...
}
```

Many people do not realize that Perl passes arguments to subroutines by reference. `@_` contains **aliases** to the arguments of a subroutine.

So you can avoid copying your arguments by working with `@_` directly:

```
foo( $big_scalar );

sub foo {
    ..do stuff with $_[0]...
    .. sneakily risk modifying $big_scalar ..
}
```

Of course, this is risky, since if you modify the value, you will modify the calling value.  Use this only when you need to save a BIG file copy.  (Or you explicitly want to modify a calling argument.)

If I need to move a big, chunk of data around, but am not going to modify it, I usually pass it by reference explicitly, rather than messing around with `@_`;

```
foo( \$big_scalar );
sub foo {
    my $bar = shift;
    ... do stuff with $$bar ...
    ... can modify $big_scalar, but the pass by ref is explicit ...
}
```

### [P]remature optimization is the root of all evil

At least that's what Donald Knuth rather famously said.  There is a lot of wisdom in this statement.

Incorrect optimization (code that purports to be an optimization, but isn't) is pretty bad, too.

Code for clarity first.
Be sure to profile your code to find bottlenecks.
Be sure to benchmark your optimizations, to make sure they work.
Document your optimized code, keep some benchmark code handy -- tomorrow's compiler may not respond the same way as today's.

Comment: And write tests while you are at it.  It really sucks to "optimize" code and have it start behaving differently.

Comment: Actually, Tony Hoare was the one who ssaid that about premature optimization. Knuth merely quoted him.

Comment: Interesting.  Looks like Knuth says Hoare said it.  Hoare says he didn't, and it may be "common folklore" or due to Dijkstra.

Answer (score 3):

I'm with Chas, benchmark and profile your code first.  I really doubt string copying is your bottleneck and you'll waste an awful lot of time for little gain.  Even if string copying does appear to be the bottleneck, look for a flawed algorithm in your code first.  One of the great potential performance boosts of Perl over C and Java is because it's so fast to write code it leaves you with plenty of extra time to profile and optimize and improve the algorithm.

If string copying really is your bottleneck, consider simply passing around large strings as references.  The moral equivalent of a string pointer in C.  This will prevent copying.  Remember to dereference them before you use them.

```
sub foo {
    my $ref = shift;

    print $$ref;
}

$string = "Some string";
foo(\$string);
```

Answer (score 0):

> I remember reading in some article (please comment if you can place it) that you can hint perl that you will not modify some variable and thus it removes the extra baggage that is otherwise required if you were to modify it etc?

Would I be right in assuming you are talking about '[use constant](http://www.perl.com/doc/manual/html/lib/constant.html)...'  ?

Comment: No. Infact I read "somewhere" that use constant should not be "used" anymore as it can blow up and there is a better replacement for it (and I forget what it is again)

Comment: Readonly (and its companion Readonly::XS) is the alternative to the constant pragma.  The constant pragma is nice because if it can collapse the value at compile time it will (e.g. sleep MINUTE*1; becomes sleep 60;), but Readonly is nice because it is a normal scalar and can used as such (interpolation, references, etc.).  Readonly is also nicer for constant complex structures like AoAs.